# hatom-feed entry-title error in the rich snippets tool

Tags: html

I am using wordpresss cms. I am trying to get things right with Google's rich snippets tool. Though, I have able to set `updated`, `author` and 'entry-title' correctly I am still having trouble setting my title in a correct way. In the [rich snippets testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) I am having this `Error: Missing required field “entry-title”.` I tried a solution that was [suggested here](http://fivera.net/hatom-feed-hatom-entry-error-wordpress-solution/) but it did not work. Below is the code that I tried.

```
<h1 class="entry-title"><? php the_title();?></h1>
```

FYI, I also use wordpress seo plugin by yoast. I thought about asking this at webmasters-stackexchange but thought I will ask here first as it might be related to wordpress. The other reason I need to get this sorted is, coz I am getting errors in my search results as displayed within google webmasters tools. 
[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this fixed. I sought for help [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!mydiscussions/webmasters/6j-p6IGoduc) in webmaster-forums and took a hint from an [article here](http://www.davidtiong.com/fix-hatom-microformats-at-least-one-field-must-be-set-for-hatomentry/). The thing that I was missing was that the entire mark-up must be within within a class named `hentry`.

My title was outside the `hentry` class so google-bot was not able to extract the structured data properly. All credits to @markratledge for putting me in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your page source and see if your html markup actually contains the entry-title class, i.e.:

`<h1 class="entry-title">My Page Title</h1>`

as it must for the span and other classes for date and author.

If it does, clear your cache and try Google's testing tool again. If your page source does not contain the correct markup, be sure you have edited the correct page template. Themes can contain several different templates for pages.

Dev Tools are great for this sort of thing; use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what's loading on your site and how to work with and change the CSS and HTML.

Comment: I have my cache cleared and have the correct `<h1 class="post-title entry-title">this is example title</h1>` in the source.  Any idea, if something else might be wrong ?

Comment: I'd ask in the Google Forums for Webmaster's Tools and the Structured Data Tool